# Getting another player's coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there an easy way to get the coordinates of a specific player using command blocks? I was trying to find a way to do this but I could not find any info about it.

Comment: It really kind of depends on what you want to *do* with these coordinates. That said, I think it *might* be possible to return PlayerX PlayerY and PlayerZ as a scoreboard. I'm not sure. If you want to do something with those coordinates, other commands will be your friend.

Comment: @Unionhawk It was made possible by WubbiConcepts and improved by staffehn. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cThnjDTxUUQ

Comment: If you just want specific players' coordinates displayed in chat screen, this command will do it without affecting gameplay : /tp <Player/Entity> ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible for now, unless using special plugins (when you are running a Bukkit server or something like that). You can only get your own coordinates by using `F3`.

Sole_Wolf commented that you can use the Bukkit plugin [MapCoOrds](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-mods/mapcoords/) if you are running a server in the possible duplicate passage that I suggested.

You can also use a map to see other players, but other players can see you as well. Also, you can't get their exact coordinates.

If you are targeting a specific player in a command, simply type their name on the `<Player>` tag or do `@p` for nearest player, `@r` for random player or `@a` for all players.

Comment: You could also use Essentials' `/whois [playername]` which lists their prefix, nicknames (if any), locations, money etc.

Comment: @Vanguard66 Is my answer OK? If yes please press the tick thing.

Comment: @aytimothy really? I thought `/whois` no longer exists XD

Comment: I remembered using it on a 1.7.10 server on a 1.8 client. Either it's still there, or that server is running an older version of Essentials (1.6 release was the last time I saw the `/whois` command)